# Downloading Docker Images from Docker Hub without using Docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I want to manually download a Docker Image from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/). More specifically, I want to download a Docker Image from Docker Hub on a machine in a restricted environment which does not (and cannot) have the Docker client software installed. I would have thought that this would be possible using the [official API](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/docker/reference/api/docker-io_api/), but this does not appear to be the case - see the following discussion:

- [Fetch docker images without docker command. e.g. with wget](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1016)

Is it really the case that the API doesn't support downloading images? Is there a way to work around this?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I came across the following ServerFault post:

- [Downloading docker image for transfer to non-internet-connected machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/701248/downloading-docker-image-for-transfer-to-non-internet-connected-machine)

The [accepted solution](https://serverfault.com/a/718470/264818) uses the `docker save` command, which doesn't help in my situation. But [another solution posted there](https://serverfault.com/a/823571/264818) cites the following StackOverflow post:

- [Pulling docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381442/pulling-docker-images/25072118)

[One of the solutions there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25072118/4451345) refers to a command-line tool called [docker-registry-debug](https://github.com/samalba/docker-registry-debug) which, among other things, can generate a `curl` command for downloading an image. Here is what I got:

```
user@host:~$ docker-registry-debug curlme docker ubuntu

# Reading user/passwd from env var "USER_CREDS"
# No password provided, disabling auth
# Getting token from https://index.docker.io
# Got registry endpoint from the server: https://registry-1.docker.io
# Got token: signature=1234567890abcde1234567890abcde1234567890,repository="library/docker",access=read
curl -i --location-trusted -I -X GET -H "Authorization: Token signature=1234567890abcde1234567890abcde1234567890,repository="library/docker",access=read" https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/images/ubuntu/layer

user@host:~$ curl \
-i --location-trusted -I -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Token signature=1234567890abcde1234567890abcde1234567890,repository="library/docker",access=read" 

https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/images/ubuntu/layer
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
Server: gunicorn/18.0
Date: Wed, 29 Nov 2017 01:00:00 GMT
Expires: -1
Content-Type: application/json
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 29
X-Docker-Registry-Version: 0.8.15
X-Docker-Registry-Config: common
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

So unfortunately it looks like the `curl` command generated does not work.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

It looks like I'm able to download layer blobs from Docker Hub. Here is how I'm currently going about it.

Get an authorization token:

```
user@host:~$ export TOKEN=\
"$(curl \
--silent \
--header 'GET' \
"https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/ubuntu:pull" \
| jq -r '.token' \
)"
```

Pull an image manifest:

```
user@host:~$ curl \
--silent \
--request 'GET' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/latest' \
| jq '.'
```

Pull an image manifest and extract the blob sums:

```
user@host:~$ curl \
--silent \
--request 'GET' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/latest' \
| jq -r '.fsLayers[].blobSum'

sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4
sha256:be588e74bd348ce48bb7161350f4b9d783c331f37a853a80b0b4abc0a33c569e
sha256:e4ce6c3651b3a090bb43688f512f687ea6e3e533132bcbc4a83fb97e7046cea3
sha256:421e436b5f80d876128b74139531693be9b4e59e4f1081c9a3c379c95094e375
sha256:4c7380416e7816a5ab1f840482c9c3ca8de58c6f3ee7f95e55ad299abbfe599f
sha256:660c48dd555dcbfdfe19c80a30f557ac57a15f595250e67bfad1e5663c1725bb
```

Download a single layer blob and write it to a file:

```
user@host:~$ BLOBSUM=\
"sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"

user@host:~$ curl \
--silent \
--location \
--request GET \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/blobs/${BLOBSUM}" \
> "${BLOBSUM/*:/}.gz"
```

Write all of the blob sums to a file:

```
user@host:~$ curl \
--silent \
--request 'GET' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/latest' \
| jq -r '.fsLayers[].blobSum' > ubuntu-blobsums.txt
```

Download all of the layer blobs from the manifest:

```
user@host:~$ while read BLOBSUM; do
curl \
--silent \
--location \
--request 'GET' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/blobs/${BLOBSUM}" \
> "${BLOBSUM/*:/}.gz"; \
done < blobsums.txt
```

Now I have a bunch of layer blobs and I need to recombine them into an image - I think.

---

Related Links:

- [Docker Community Forums: **Docker Hub API retrieve images**](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-hub-api-retrieve-images/23046)
- [Docker Community Forums: **Manual download of Docker Hub images**](https://forums.docker.com/t/manual-download-of-docker-hub-images/26073)
- [Docker Issue #1016: **Fetch docker images without docker command. e.g. with wget**](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1016)
- [ServerFault: **Downloading docker image for transfer to non-internet-connected machine**](https://serverfault.com/questions/701248/downloading-docker-image-for-transfer-to-non-internet-connected-machine)
- [StackOverflow: **Downloading docker image for transfer to non-internet-connected machine**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381442/pulling-docker-images/)
- [StackOverflow: **How to download docker images without using pull command?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905763/how-to-download-docker-images-without-using-pull-command)
- [StackOverflow: **Is there a way to download docker hub images without “docker pull” for a machine with out Internet access?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402513/is-there-a-way-to-download-docker-hub-images-whitout-docker-pull-for-a-machine)
- [StackOverflow: **Docker official registry (Docker Hub) URL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198392/docker-official-registry-docker-hub-url)

Comment: "More specifically, I want to download a Docker Image from Docker Hub on a machine in a restricted environment which does not (and cannot) have the Docker client software installed." => What's the point to have the images on this machine then ? (easier workaround is using a pivot host, one where you acn docker pull from dockerhub and docker save/ docker push to an internal registry after)

Comment: @Tensibai To copy it to another machine that *does* have Docker but *doesn't* have internet access.

Comment: Did you had a look at the docker pull code? It sounds the way to go to build something like this from basic http calls

Comment: @Tensibai I think I figured it out. I also think I got a solution from the Docker community. I'll come back and post the solution later today.

Comment: @Tensibai I posted [a solution](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/2772/3070) with a shell script that solves the problem.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to give the docker host Internet access by using the other as a proxy

Comment: @Marged That wasn't an option. The server was configured in such a way that it could not easily be used as a proxy.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It turned out that the [Moby Project](https://mobyproject.org/) has a shell script on the [Moby Github](https://github.com/moby/moby/) which can download images from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) in a format that can be imported into Docker:

- [download-frozen-image-v2.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/master/contrib/download-frozen-image-v2.sh)

The usage syntax for the script is given by the following:

```bash
download-frozen-image-v2.sh target_dir image[:tag][@digest] ...
```

The image can then be imported with `tar` and `docker load`:

```bash
tar -cC 'target_dir' . | docker load
```

To verify that the script works as expected, I downloaded an Ubuntu image from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) and loaded it into Docker:

```bash
user@host:~$ bash download-frozen-image-v2.sh ubuntu ubuntu:latest
user@host:~$ tar -cC 'ubuntu' . | docker load
user@host:~$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu bash
root@1dd5e62113b9:/#
```

In practice I would have to first copy the data from the internet client (which does *not* have Docker installed) to the target/destination machine (which *does* have Docker installed):

```bash
user@nodocker:~$ bash download-frozen-image-v2.sh ubuntu ubuntu:latest
user@nodocker:~$ tar -C 'ubuntu' -cf 'ubuntu.tar' .
user@nodocker:~$ scp ubuntu.tar user@hasdocker:~
```

and then load and use the image on the target host:

```bash
user@hasdocker:~ docker load ubuntu.tar
user@hasdocker:~ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu bash
root@1dd5e62113b9:/#
```

Comment: `The machine with internet connectivity does not and cannot have Docker installed`. but you apply `docker load`

Comment: @030 Just to test/demonstrate that the script works and that the download image data can be imported into Docker. In practice I would first have to copy the data to a machine with Docker installed.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that part for clarification

Comment: @030 I added an example session illustrating what the workflow would look like in practice.

Answer (score 20):

There is a tool called [Skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) which can retrieve Docker images from a repository and save them in several formats.

For example:

1. Download the image and save the layers as a tarball:
   `skopeo copy docker://ubuntu docker-archive:/tmp/ubuntu.tar:ubuntu`
2. Transfer `/tmp/ubuntu.tar` to another machine if desired.
3. Load the image on a Docker instance which does not have internet connection:
   `docker load --input /tmp/ubuntu.tar`

It is available in CentOS 7 repo with the package name `skopeo`. There are no Debian or Ubuntu packages at this time (but it is easy to compile).

Comment: FWIW there are deb packages now: https://github.com/containers/skopeo/blob/master/install.md

Answer (score 5):

thanks for motivation.
I made a powershell version of it.
Check it out...
With it you can move in dockerhub containers to a restricted docker networks with a windows desktop and an ssh-scp tool to docker machine without root or administrator rights

https://gitlab.com/Jancsoj78/dockerless_docker_downloader
a new hacker tool :)

```
$image = "ubuntu"
$tag = "latest"
$imageuri = "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/"+$image+":pull"
$taguri = "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/"+$image+"/manifests/"+$tag
$bloburi = "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/"+$image+"/blobs/sha256:"

#token request
$token = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $imageuri | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -expand token

#pull image manifest
$blobs = $($(Invoke-Webrequest -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $token"} -Method GET -Uri $taguri | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -expand fsLayers ) -replace "sha256:" -replace "@{blobSum=" -replace "}")

#download blobs
for ($i=0; $i -lt $blobs.length; $i++) {
    $blobelement =$blobs[$i]

    Invoke-Webrequest -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $token"} -Method GET -Uri $bloburi$blobelement -OutFile blobtmp

    $source = "blobtmp"
    $newfile = "$blobelement.gz"

#overwrite
Copy-Item $source $newfile -Force -Recurse
#source blobs
ls *.gz
}
#postprocess
echo "copy these .gz to your docker machine"
echo "docker import .gz backward one by one"
echo "lastone with ubuntu:latest"
echo "after docker export and reimport to make a simple layer image"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an adapted python script, thus having an OS independant solution: [docker-drag](https://github.com/NotGlop/docker-drag)

Use it like that, and it will create a TAR archive that you will be able to import using docker load :

```
python docker_pull.py hello-world
python docker_pull.py alpine:3.9
python docker_pull.py kalilinux/kali-linux-docker
```

Comment: If you close your github account there's nothing left, if you're ok with sharing it, keep the link but paste the script here also please. You can [edit] your answer, paste your code and then select it and type ctrl+K or the `{}` (code) button in the editor top bar to format it.

Comment: I would love to paste the code here but it is 100 lines long and I don't think it will be readable. Nevertheless, you can fork the code to save your own copy of the script.

Comment: That's not for me, that to have an answer which is self sustaining, if the link break, do you really think this may help someone reading this answer in a few months ? (btw the maximum size for an answer is 30k characters)

Comment: You could put this in pip. I find it very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To me it is not completely clear what you are trying to achieve and why the attempts are not a solution for the problem. If I would need to solve this issue I would like @Tensibai and other Q&As indicated, do a docker pull first on a system with internet connectivity, save the docker image, copy it to the machine without internet connectivity, load the image and run it.

**Demonstration**

There are no images on system A:

```
userA@systemA ~ $ docker images
REPOSITORY        TAG               IMAGE ID          CREATED             SIZE
userA@systemA ~ $
```

Pull an image from dockerhub:

```
userA@systemA ~ $
docker pull nginx
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
bc95e04b23c0: Pull complete 
f3186e650f4e: Pull complete 
9ac7d6621708: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:b81f317384d7388708a498555c28a7cce778a8f291d90021208b3eba3fe74887
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
userA@systemA ~ $ docker images
REPOSITORY        TAG               IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx             latest            9e7424e5dbae        10 days ago         108MB
```

Save docker image:

```
userA@systemA ~ $ docker save nginx -o nginx.tar
```

Copy docker image to systemB and load it.

```
userB@systemB ~ $ docker load -i nginx.tar
cec7521cdf36: Loading layer  58.44MB/58.44MB
350d50e58b6c: Loading layer  53.76MB/53.76MB
63c39cd4a775: Loading layer  3.584kB/3.584kB
Loaded image: nginx:latest
userB@systemB ~ $ docker images
REPOSITORY        TAG               IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx             latest            9e7424e5dbae        10 days ago         108MB
```

Comment: The machine with internet connectivity does not and cannot have Docker installed. The question is asking for a way to download an image *without* using the Docker client. See [my solution](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/2772/3070).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand [Jancsó's](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/6666/28888) way of postprocessing, so I've spent some time to modify his script and here's what I came with:

https://github.com/meetyourturik/dockerless-docker-downloader

upd: apparently, 'a link only answer...' is something bad, so here's a whole script:

```
# Workaround for SelfSigned Cert an force TLS 1.2
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# use 'library/' prefix for 'official' images like postgres 
$image = "atlassian/jira-software" 
$tag = "8.13.2" 

$imageuri = "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${image}:pull" 
$taguri = "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${image}/manifests/${tag}"
$bloburi = "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${image}/blobs/" 

# generating folder to save image files 
$path = "$image$tag" -replace '[\\/":*?<>|]'
if (!(test-path $path)) { 
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path 
} 

# token request 
$token = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $imageuri | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -expand token 

# getting image manifest 
$headers = @{} 
$headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer $token") 
# this header is needed to get manifest in correct format: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/ 
$headers.add("Accept", "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json") 
$manifest = Invoke-Webrequest -Headers $headers -Method GET -Uri $taguri | ConvertFrom-Json 

# downloading config json 
$configSha = $manifest | Select -expand config | Select -expand digest 
$config = ".\$path\config.json" 
Invoke-Webrequest -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $token"} -Method GET -Uri $bloburi$configSha -OutFile $config 

# generating manifest.json 
$manifestJson = @{} 
$manifestJson.add("Config", "config.json") 
$manifestJson.add("RepoTags",@("${image}:${tag}")) 

# downloading layers 
$layers = $manifest | Select -expand layers | Select -expand digest 
$blobtmp = ".\$path\blobtmp" 

#downloading blobs 
$layersJson = @() 
foreach ($blobelement in $layers) { 
    # making so name doesnt start with 'sha256:' 
    $fileName = "$blobelement.gz" -replace 'sha256:' 
    $newfile = ".\$path\$fileName" 
    $layersJson += @($fileName) 

    # token expired after 5 minutes, so requesting new one for every blob just in case 
    $token = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $imageuri | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -expand token 
    
    Invoke-Webrequest -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $token"} -Method GET -Uri $bloburi$blobelement -OutFile $blobtmp 
    
    Copy-Item $blobtmp $newfile -Force -Recurse 
} 

# removing temporary blob 
Remove-Item $blobtmp 

# saving manifest.json 
$manifestJson.add("Layers", $layersJson) 
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 -InputObject @($manifestJson) | Out-File -Encoding ascii ".\$path\manifest.json" 

# postprocessing
echo "copy generated folder to your docker machine" 
echo "tar -cvf imagename.tar *" 
echo "docker load < imagename.tar"
```

after sctipt downloads blobs and generates config and manifest jsons download it to docker machine and execute two following commands:

```
tar -cvf imagename.tar *
docker load < imagename.tar
```

first creates an archive, 2nd uploads image archive to docker

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that could be used to download docker images is [P2IWD](https://github.com/030/p2iwd).

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be any code in that repository.

Comment: @igal version 0.1.0 has been released. It is capable to download docker images from a Nexus3 server and to upload them to another one.

Answer (score -1):

If your company has nexus or a similar repository, they may already have set up nexus to pull in what you need. You could try adding your repo's host/ip in front of the relative docker hub path.

Examples:

```
docker pull nexus.example.com:18443/nginx
docker pull nexus.example.com:18443/selenium/node-chrome
docker pull nexus.example.com:18443/postgres:9.4
```